# Does WCF support Dynamic Parameters?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Does WCF support Dynamic Parameters or Anon Objects?

Can it still work without DataContracts?

like this

```
//  The Service
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMath
{
    [OperationContract]
    string Add(Object param);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can Call a WCF service from a client without having the contract interface..

For More Details check the following link it il helpful for u

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/328552/Calling-a-WCF-service-from-a-client-without-having